# Interpolate time series data from one df to time axis of another df in Python polars

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, interpolation, python-polars

I have time series data on different time axes in different dataframes. I need to interpolate data from one `df` to onto the time axis of another df, `df_ref`. Ex:

```py
import polars as pl

# DataFrame with the reference time axis:
df_ref = pl.DataFrame({"dt": ["2022-12-14T14:00:01.000", "2022-12-14T14:00:02.000",
                              "2022-12-14T14:00:03.000", "2022-12-14T14:00:04.000",
                              "2022-12-14T14:00:05.000", "2022-12-14T14:00:06.000"]})
df_ref = df_ref.with_column(pl.col("dt").str.strptime(pl.Datetime).cast(pl.Datetime))

# DataFrame with a different frequency time axis, to be interpolated onto the reference time axis:
df = pl.DataFrame({
        "dt": ["2022-12-14T14:00:01.500", "2022-12-14T14:00:03.500", "2022-12-14T14:00:05.500"],
        "v1": [1.5, 3.5, 5.5]})
df = df.with_column(pl.col("dt").str.strptime(pl.Datetime).cast(pl.Datetime))
```

I cannot `join` the dfs since keys don't match:

```py
print(df_ref.join(df, on="dt", how="left").interpolate())
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬──────┐
│ dt                  ┆ v1   │
│ ---                 ┆ ---  │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64  │
╞═════════════════════╪══════╡
│ 2022-12-14 14:00:01 ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 14:00:02 ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 14:00:03 ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 14:00:04 ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 14:00:05 ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 14:00:06 ┆ null │
└─────────────────────┴──────┘
```

So my 'iterative' approach would be to interpolate each column individually, for instance like

```py
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

f = interp1d(df["dt"].dt.timestamp(), df["v1"],
             kind="linear", bounds_error=False, fill_value="extrapolate")

out = f(df_ref["dt"].dt.timestamp())
df_ref = df_ref.with_column(pl.Series(out).alias("v1_interp"))

print(df_ref.head(6))
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬───────────┐
│ dt                  ┆ v1_interp │
│ ---                 ┆ ---       │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64       │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 2022-12-14 14:00:01 ┆ 1.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 14:00:02 ┆ 2.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 14:00:03 ┆ 3.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 14:00:04 ┆ 4.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 14:00:05 ┆ 5.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 14:00:06 ┆ 6.0       │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

Although this gives the result I need, I wonder if there is a more idiomatic approach? I hesitate to mention efficiency here since I haven't benchmarked this with real data yet ("measure, don't guess!"). However, I'd assume that a native implementation in the underlying Rust code could add some performance benefits.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [.join_asof()](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join_asof.html#polars.DataFrame.join_asof) with its `tolerance=` parameter.

Comment: The merge can be done by making the date format of df1 the same. I am new to polars, but I got the result by referring to [this content](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4575). `df1 = df1.with_column(pl.col("dt").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f', strict=False).cast(pl.Datetime))`

Comment: @jqurious I had a look at `join_asof`, as I understand the docs ("*similar to a left-join except that we match on nearest key*"), that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @r-beginners the question is not limited to a datetime dtype axis; see my example, for interpolation you'll need a numeric representation anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scipy.interpolate.interpol1d` example ends up calling [this function.](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.9.3/scipy/interpolate/_interpolate.py#L631-L658)

You could use the same approach and process each column with `.map()`

```
def polars_ip(df_ref, df):
   old = df["dt"].dt.timestamp().to_numpy()
   new = df_ref["dt"].dt.timestamp().to_numpy()

   hi = np.searchsorted(old, new).clip(1, len(old) - 1)
   lo = hi - 1

   def _interp(column):
      column = column.to_numpy()
      slope = (column[hi] - column[lo]) / (old[hi] - old[lo])
      return pl.Series(slope * (new - old[lo]) + column[lo])
      
   values = (
      pl.concat([df, df_ref], how="diagonal")
        .select(pl.exclude("dt").map(_interp))
   )
   values.columns = [f"{name}_ref_ip" for name in values.columns]
   
   return df_ref.hstack(values)
```

```
>>> %time polars_ip(df_ref, df)
CPU times: user 48.1 ms, sys: 20.4 ms, total: 68.5 ms
Wall time: 22 ms
shape: (85536, 11)
```

```
>>> %time scipy_ip(df_ref, df)
CPU times: user 75.5 ms, sys: 5.51 ms, total: 81 ms
Wall time: 74.3 ms
shape: (85536, 11)
```

Check they return the same values:

```
>>> polars_ip(df_ref, df).frame_equal(scipy_ip(df_ref, df))
True
```

You can also generate the same values using:

```
N_COLS = 10
names = list(map(str, range(N_COLS)))
has_reading = pl.col(names[0]).is_not_null()
has_no_reading = has_reading.is_not()
(
   pl.concat([df, df_ref], how="diagonal")
   .sort("dt")
   .with_columns([
      pl.when(has_reading).then(pl.all())
        .shift(-1).backward_fill().suffix("_hi"),
      pl.when(has_reading).then(pl.all())
        .shift(+1).forward_fill().suffix("_lo")
      ])
   .with_columns([
      pl.when(has_reading).then(pl.col(r"^.+_hi$"))
        .forward_fill().backward_fill(),
      pl.when(has_reading).then(pl.col(r"^.+_lo$"))
        .backward_fill().forward_fill()
      ])
   .filter(has_no_reading)
   .with_column(
      pl.col(r"^dt.*$").dt.timestamp().suffix("_ts"))
   .with_columns([
      (((pl.col(f"{name}_hi")  - pl.col(f"{name}_lo")) 
         / (pl.col("dt_hi_ts") - pl.col("dt_lo_ts")))
         * (pl.col("dt_ts")    - pl.col("dt_lo_ts")) 
         + pl.col(f"{name}_lo"))
         .alias(f"{name}_ref_ip") for name in names
      ])
   .select([
      pl.col("dt"), pl.col("^.+_ref_ip$")
   ])
)
```

Comment: thank you for trying to convince me of `join_asof` ;-) Can this be adapted to work on multiple columns in one step (I mean in the Python code)? Otherwise, it would seem way more complicated (at least in terms of readability) than using scipy's interpolate.

Comment: I've added a little comparison for correctness and performance below; please apologize if I made any mistakes adapting your approach. The example in the question might not have been ideal as well.

Comment: Processing all columns is a simple enough adaption - I've added an example. It's not fully correct though, the first row of output is wrong and the rest of the values are slightly off.

Comment: I've updated my "summary post". Although this seems to be relatively good performance-wise, correctness is far away from acceptable in my eyes.

Comment: Yes, it's not a valid solution and should be removed. It just happens to generate the output for your simplified example.

Comment: Thank you for your effort anyways. I'm still kind of surprised that this is not a built-in feature. I mean it's not in pandas but my scipy solution is just fine there. But polars aims for higher performance, no? `xarray` [has it](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/interpolation.html), so maybe I should open a feature request?

Comment: Yes - maybe you should.

Comment: I was curious and took a closer look at what the scipy function does. It uses a few lines of numpy. I've edited the answer to show how you could use the same approach.

Answer (score 1):

**First approach**

I think this is one of those problems where you want to create a ton more rows than you actually want to end up and then filter back down to what you want.

Because polars's `interpolate` function only computes missing values in between known values rather than extrapolating forward and backwards, let's make our first step to manually extrapolate df1 to add an extra row before and after.

```
df1=df1.lazy()
df1=pl.concat([df1,
        df1.sort('dt').with_row_count('n') \
            .select(
                    [pl.col('n')] + \
                    [pl.when(pl.col('n')<=1) \
                       .then(pl.col(x)-(pl.col(x).shift(-1)-pl.col(x))) \
                    .when(pl.col('n')>=pl.col('n').max()-1) \
                       .then(pl.col(x)+(pl.col(x)-pl.col(x).shift(1)))
                               for x in df1.columns]
                ) \
        .filter((pl.col('n')==0) | (pl.col('n')==pl.col('n').max())) \
        .select(pl.exclude('n'))]).sort('dt')
```

I'm using a list comprehension in the `select` so this should be extensible to any number of columns.

The next thing to do is make a df with a dt column that starts with the earliest dt and ends with the latest between df0 and df1 with the minimum time difference.  By fixing the difference in your key column, it allows polars's `interpolate` to work as you expect.

```
specs = pl.concat([df0.select('dt'),df1.select('dt')]) \
          .sort('dt').select([
                       pl.col('dt').min().alias('mindt'),
                       pl.col('dt').max().alias('maxdt'), 
                       (pl.col('dt')-pl.col('dt').shift()).min().alias('mindiff')
                      ]).collect()


newdf = pl.DataFrame({'dt':pl.date_range(specs[0,0], specs[0,1], specs[0,2])}).lazy()
```

Alternatively you can make `newdf` with a list comprehension incase dt isn't a datetime `pl.DataFrame({'dt': [specs[0,0] + specs[0,2]*x for x in range(int(1+(specs[0,1]-specs[0,0])/specs[0,2]))]}).lazy()`

With that you do an outer join between that and your two dfs then use the embedded `interpolate` to get all the values you're looking for.  You can chain a filter and select at the end to match your output.

```
newdf = newdf.join(df0, on='dt', how='outer') \
    .join(df1, on='dt', how='outer') \
    .with_columns([pl.col(x).interpolate().suffix('_interp') for x in df1.columns if x != 'dt']) \
    .filter(~pl.col('v0').is_null()).select(pl.exclude('v1')) \
    .collect()
```

**Second approach**

Another way to tackle the problem is to essentially recreate the scipy interpolate function with a bunch of shift and whenthen statements...

First you do a diagonal concat and then add a bunch of helper columns representing the dt and v1 columns but shifted, one pair for a forward shift and another pair for backwards.  Then calculate the change in `v1` by the time difference which is then itself carried forwards and backwards.  Almost lastly is whenthen logic for begining/ending/middle rows.  True lastly, is filtering and selecting away the helper columns.

```
    pl.concat([df0, df1], how='diagonal').sort('dt') \
    .with_column(pl.when(~pl.col('v1').is_null()).then(pl.col('dt')).alias('v1dt')) \
    .with_columns([
        pl.col('v1').fill_null(strategy='forward').alias('v1_for'),
        pl.col('v1dt').fill_null(strategy='forward').alias('v1dt_for'),
        pl.col('v1').fill_null(strategy='backward').alias('v1_back'),
        pl.col('v1dt').fill_null(strategy='backward').alias('v1dt_back')
        ]) \
    .with_column(((pl.col('v1_back')-pl.col('v1_for'))/(pl.col('v1dt_back')-pl.col('v1dt_for'))).alias('diff')) \
    .with_column((pl.when(pl.col('diff').is_nan()).then(None).otherwise(pl.col('diff'))).alias('diff')) \
    .with_column(pl.col('diff').fill_null(strategy='forward').fill_null(strategy='backward')) \
    .with_column((pl.when(~pl.col('v1').is_null()).then(pl.col('v1')) \
                .when((~pl.col('v1_for').is_null()) & (~pl.col('v1_back').is_null())) \
                        .then((pl.col('dt')-pl.col('v1dt_for'))*pl.col('diff')+pl.col('v1_for')) \
                .when(~pl.col('v1_back').is_null()) \
                        .then(pl.col('v1_back')-(pl.col('v1dt_back')-pl.col('dt'))*pl.col('diff')) \
                .otherwise(pl.col('v1_for')+(pl.col('dt')-pl.col('v1dt_for'))*pl.col('diff'))).alias('v1_interp')) \
    .filter(~pl.col('v0').is_null()).select(['dt','v0','v1_interp'])
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Actually, I misread your introductory statement at first, and thought you were suggesting I'm over-engineering things ;-) You might have a point there, although maybe not intentional. I'll have to try your solution in practice.

Comment: @FObersteiner  thought of a second way to do it so I put it in the answer

Comment: I've tried to add a comparison with some more realistic data than in the example in the question. Please apologize if I made any mistakes adapting your approach! Also, only the second one worked "out-of-the-box" with some minor modifications, the first one errored out, still trying to find out what goes wrong.